# Unreachable states when rotating rows and columns on a 3x3 grid

Tags: game-theory, invariance

I came up with this problem when I'm randomly playing around with my poker cards: first, arrange the cards $1$ to $9$ in a $3 \times 3$ grid:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

then, rotate the rows and columns, i.e., a row
$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$
may become
$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
2 & 3 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$
(left-rotate)
or
$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
3 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$
(right-rotate),
and similarly for columns (up-rotate or down-rotate).

The question: given an unlimited amount of row- and column-rotations,
is it possible to transform the given state into the following state?
(i.e., swap the $8$ and $9$ without changing the other cards)

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
7 & 9 & 8 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

---

I have been playing with the cards, without success.  I get pretty close, but I can't produce the exact state.  I am starting to suspect this is impossible.  But I am unsure how to prove it.

I try to divide the $3 \times 3$ grid into three areas $A, B, C$:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & C \\
\hline
B & C & A \\
\hline
C & A & B \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

and somehow come up with an invariant.  However, I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: odd/even permutations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each rotation of a row or column is an even permutation. The product of even permutations is again an even permutation. Swapping $8$ and $9$ is an odd permutation. Thus you can’t reach it by performing such rotations.